# Relational database design issue - category scoped tags

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm designing a database where I have a number of products, each of which belongs to one and only one category.

Products are meant to be tagged, but only with tags allowed for the category they belong to.

This is what I've got so far:

[image: database diagram]

Let's say I have these 2 categories:

- Smartphones
- Laptops

Tags for the "Smartphones" category:

- Dual SIM
- GPS

Tags for the "Laptop" category:

- Backlit keyboard
- HDMI

The problem with this design is that the database doesn't prevent a product from being tagged with a tag from another category: a bug in my app's code could easily cause a laptop to be tagged with the "Dual SIM" tag, which obviously is not what I want.

I would like to prevent this situation at database level with foreign keys and without using triggers. Is this possible at all?

Comment: Why not just put in a secondary key in your products? So that Dual SIM has product id X and must be used with category id Y etc.? Then you can't reuse products for different categories - but it solves your need.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. Are you suggesting to add a new field to the products table?

Comment: Yes. So that your products/tags belong to a specific category - this is then maintained when you add new products/tags to categories

Comment: There is already a "category_id" field in both the products and tags tables. So each product and each tag already belongs to a category.

Comment: Sorry, not in your product_tag table, but in your tag table. Each tag should be specified to which category it can belong. You can never get it to "guess" how the FK should be, so you need to specify which category_ids and which product_ids are allowed to match.

Comment: If you look at my diagram, there is already a field called "category_id" in the "tag" table.

Comment: Lets say you have a tag called "Dual Sim", you need to specify, in the table where the tag exists, that it is only allowed to be used on a specific product/category or both. Add product_id in tag table and/or category_id, depending on your end goal.

Comment: Google subtypes & polymorphism in sql/databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do the following in Oracle. Note how the last insert fails, I believe this is what you are after.

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id            INTEGER NOT NULL,
    category_id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id ),
    CONSTRAINT uq_prod_cat UNIQUE ( id,category_id )
);

INSERT INTO product (
    id,
    category_id
) VALUES (
    1,
    1
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
    id            INTEGER NOT NULL,
    category_id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id ),
    CONSTRAINT uq_tag_cat UNIQUE ( id,category_id )
);

INSERT INTO tags (
    id,
    category_id
) VALUES (
    1,
    1
);

INSERT INTO tags (
    id,
    category_id
) VALUES (
    2,
    1
);

INSERT INTO tags (
    id,
    category_id
) VALUES (
    3,
    2
);

CREATE TABLE product_tags (
    id            INTEGER NOT NULL,
    product_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    category_id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    tag_id        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( product_id,category_id )
        REFERENCES product ( id,category_id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( tag_id,category_id )
        REFERENCES tags ( id,category_id )
);

INSERT INTO product_tags (
    id,
    product_id,
    category_id,
    tag_id
) VALUES (
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1
);

1 row inserted.

INSERT INTO product_tags (
    id,
    product_id,
    category_id,
    tag_id
) VALUES (
    2,
    1,
    1,
    2
);

1 row inserted.

INSERT INTO product_tags (
    id,
    product_id,
    category_id,
    tag_id
) VALUES (
    3,
    1,
    1,
    3
);

Error starting at line : 35 in command -
INSERT INTO product_tags (id, product_id, category_id, tag_id) VALUES (3, 1, 1, 3)
Error report -
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYS_C008023) violated - parent key not found
```

Comment: Really good answer. I was wondering if you could recommend a book where I can study this further?

Comment: For databases, the only book I'd recommend is "Database System Concepts" by Henry F. Korth. But this is a book that explains general database concepts rather than practical knowledge about a specific DBMS. Its also very big.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is pretty similar to that of [Ashuntosh A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5945498/ashutosh-a), except that I would create a separate table for associating tags with categories, so that the schema allows for a tag to apply to more one category (e.g. both a tablet and phone could  have a DualSim):

[image: diagram]

```
--TSQL

create table ProductCategory
(
    id int primary key identity,
    name varchar(50) not null
)

create table ProductTag
(
    id int primary key identity,
    name varchar(50) not null
)

create table TagCategory
(
    tag_id int foreign key references ProductTag,
    category int foreign key references ProductCategory,
    primary key (tag_id, category)
)

create table Product
(
    id int primary key identity,
    type int foreign key references ProductCategory,
    unique (id, type)
)

create table TaggedProduct
(
    product int,
    tag int,
    type int,
    primary key (product, tag),
    foreign key (product, type) references Product (id, type),
    foreign key (tag, type) references TagCategory (tag_id, category)
)



insert ProductCategory
    select 'Laptop' union
    select 'Phone'

insert ProductTag
    select 'HDMI' union
    select 'Backlit Keyboard' union
    select 'Dual Sim' union
    select 'GPS'

insert TagCategory
    select 1, 1 union -- HDMI/LAPTOP
    select 2, 1 union -- Backlit/LAPTOP
    select 3, 2 union -- DualSim/PHONE
    select 4, 2 -- GPS/PHONE    

insert Product
    select 1 --a laptop

insert TaggedProduct
    select 1, 1, 1 --laptop has hdmi
    union select 1, 2, 1 --laptop has backlit keyboard

insert TaggedProduct select 1, 3, 1 
--fails because 'DualSim/Laptop' is not a valid category
```

Comment: good answer too, but in my specific case I don't need to share tags between categories